# Parse JSON data from URL to MySQL

Tags: python, json

I have this code sending JSON data from a URL to a MySQL database however I get the error 'String indices must be integers'

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import pymysql

mydb = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='test', passwd='test', db='test', local_infile=1)

r = requests.get('https://example.com/apidata')

cursor = mydb.cursor()

json_obj = r.json()

for ord in json_obj["0"]:
    print("stripe_token", ord["stripe_token"])

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO apidata (stripe_token) VALUES (%s)", (ord["stripe_token"]))

#close the connection to the database.
mydb.commit()
cursor.close()
```

My Json data looks like this

```
{
"0": {
"need_session_refresh": "1",
"signup_email_sent": "1",
"stripe_cc_expires": "0000",
"stripe_cc_masked": "123456",
"stripe_token": "1x734g834",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Edit - I'd like to also parse this recursively e.g

```
{
"0": {
"stripe_token": "756474745",
"need_session_refresh": "1",
},
"1": {
"nstripe_token": "34563456",
"need_session_refresh": "1",
},
"_total": 43054
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, when you iterate through a dictionary like this:

```
for ord in json_obj["0"]:
```

`ord` actually takes the values of all of the **keys** in your dictionary, not the key-value pairs. That means that when you do:

```
ord["stripe_token"]
```

`ord` is the key in the dictionary (i.e. a string) and it's complaining you can't use another string to index into a string.

I think the issue is that you are assuming that the structure inside "0" is a list rather than a dictionary. If you do `json_obj["0"]["stripe_token"]`, you should find that you get the value that you want. You can also remove the loop `for ord in json_obj["0"]:`, since there's not actually a list inside `json_obj["0"]`.

The code would then look like this:

```
json_obj = r.json()
ord = json_obj["0"]

print("stripe_token", ord["stripe_token"])

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO apidata (stripe_token) VALUES (%s)", (ord["stripe_token"]))
```

EDIT: as you've added that there are further keys inside `json_values` that you need to access, you'll need to loop over these keys to do so. The code would look like this:

```
for index in json_obj:
    if index != "_total":
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO apidata (stripe_token) VALUES (%s)", (json_obj[index]["stripe_token"]))
```

Comment: Hi Rob,

Can you show me what this would actually look like in the code as I'm now getting json_obj is not defined.

Comment: Hey, I've edited my original answer to add a code example.

Comment: Perfect thanks! If I have more thank once instance of stripe_token how do Ioop through them all. Currently it will just duplicate the first json object many times into a new row.

Comment: If you have multiple stripe_tokens, how do you envisage the structure of the JSON looking? Currently the JSON you've given will only allow for one stripe_token value.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I'm trying that and getting TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Does it say which line specifically triggered that error?

Comment: cursor.execute("INSERT INTO apidata (stripe_token) VALUES (%s)", (json_obj[index]["stripe_token"]))

Comment: Looking back at the JSON you posted, this is happening because of the "_total" key. You'll need to exclude this, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I was trying this last night but got cursor.execute("INSERT INTO apidata (stripe_token) VALUES (%s)", (json_obj[index]["stripe_token"]))
KeyError: 'stripe_token'

Comment: Do you have other items in your JSON that don't have a stripe_token? You'll have to exclude those as well, perhaps just change the if condition to `if 'stripe_token' in json_obj[index]:`

Answer (score 0):

```
for ord in json_obj["0"]:
    print("stripe_token", ord["stripe_token"])
```

Here `ord` would iterate over keys of `json_obj["0"]`. You don't need loop at all

```
print(f"stripe_token: {json_obj['0']['stripe_token']}")
```

You would need loop only if your `json_obj` has more than one element.

I would advise to properly handle the case when json object does not look like what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, but I just get  'json_obj = json.loads(r)
NameError: name 'json' is not defined'

Comment: why do you need to `json.loads(r)`? You had `json_obj = r.json()` in your code - that is convince method of the `requests.Response` object....